# use awk or sed to replace string dynamically in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a need to replace filename in a file to a string which is cp command and hence it should replace existing filename with cp source destination in same file .file is comma separated
    #m sample file

```
ABC,TS-R:56:UT-123,/apps/home/t.txt
ICA,Y6734YGSU,/apps/home/t2.txt
MDI,UI-HDGD-PO567,/apps/home/t3.txt
```

now i want a sed or awk command which can replace the `/apps/home/<filename>.txt` to `cp /apps/home/<filename>.txt /apps/cmb/<filename>.txt`

so after sed/awk same file should have contents

```
ABC,TS-R:56:UT-123,cp /apps/home/t.txt /apps/cmb/t.txt
ICA,Y6734YGSU,cp /apps/home/t2.txt /apps/cmb/t2.txt
MDI,UI-HDGD-PO567,cp /apps/home/t3.txt /apps/cmb/t3.txt
```

I tried `awk -F, '{$3="cp "$3" "$3""}1' OFS=, test.txt` but its just printing `ABC,TS-R:56:UT-123,cp /apps/home/t.txt /apps/home/t.txt` also in console and not changing in file.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F/ '{print $1"cp ",$2,$3,$4 " ",$2,"cmb",$4}' OFS=/ file
ABC,TS-R:56:UT-123,cp /apps/home/t.txt /apps/cmb/t.txt
ICA,Y6734YGSU,cp /apps/home/t2.txt /apps/cmb/t2.txt
MDI,UI-HDGD-PO567,cp /apps/home/t3.txt /apps/cmb/t3.txt
```

Comment: it works exactly as i require , but why its not make changes to file , its only printing on console from where i am trying , is it that i have to use it from script and it works ?

Comment: @innova To write it back to the file do:  `awk -F/ '{print $1"cp ",$2,$3,$4 " ",$2,"cmb",$4}' OFS=/ file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{p=$NF; sub(/\/home\//, "/cmb/", $NF); 
     $NF=sprintf("cp %s %s", p, $NF)} 1' file
ABC,TS-R:56:UT-123,cp /apps/home/t.txt /apps/cmb/t.txt
ICA,Y6734YGSU,cp /apps/home/t2.txt /apps/cmb/t2.txt
MDI,UI-HDGD-PO567,cp /apps/home/t3.txt /apps/cmb/t3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks , your's also works , i just put in "/home/cmb" and it was perfect

Answer (score 0):

Since this is simple substitutions on individual lines it'd be an appropriate job for sed:

```
$ sed -r 's:(/[^/]+/)([^/]+)(/[^/]+):cp & \1cmb\3:' file
ABC,TS-R:56:UT-123,cp /apps/home/t.txt /apps/cmb/t.txt
ICA,Y6734YGSU,cp /apps/home/t2.txt /apps/cmb/t2.txt
MDI,UI-HDGD-PO567,cp /apps/home/t3.txt /apps/cmb/t3.txt
```